# Conflict between texMemo.cls and isodate.sty?

Tags: incompatibility, isodate

This compiles properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,cleanlook]{isodate}

\begin{document}

\title{ISO package test}
\author{me}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

But this does not:

```
\documentclass{texMemo}
\usepackage[english,cleanlook]{isodate}

\memoto{you}
\memofrom{me}
\memodate{\today}
\memosubject{ISO package test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Since the document class is the only difference, I'm inferring that there's a conflict between the class and the `isodate` package. What is the conflict, and how, if at all, can I resolve it?

Miscellaneous notes:

- The `texMemo` class is available
  [here](http://www.oak-tree.us/2010/08/02/texmemo/) if you don't have
  it.
- I don't actually know how to diagnose package/class conflicts, so
  anything you tell me here is going to be new information.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get when compilation fails.

Comment: Note that many people will not download a zip file of uncertain origins merely to answer a question.

Answer (score 2):

The compilation stops with an error about `babel` and `ngerman` not loaded. Adding

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

solves this problem.

### Code

```
\documentclass{texMemo}%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[english,cleanlook]{isodate}%

\memoto{you}
\memofrom{me}
\memodate{\today}
\memosubject{ISO package test}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll try to figure out the real conflict.

**Edit**

The `datetime` package by N. Talbot provides a quite configurable alternative to `isodate` package and is by fare more up-to-date.

```
\documentclass{texMemo}%
\usepackage{datetime}

% Defining a custom date format
\newdateformat{crmdgndate}{\THEDAY~\monthname~\THEYEAR}

\memoto{you}
\memofrom{me}
\memodate{\today}
\memosubject{ISO package test}


\begin{document}
\crmdgndate%

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think the actual issue is loading `babel` (although it might solve the problem): a trace suggests something is trying to `\edef` the date, and that leads back to the line `\ifthenelse{\equal{\@memodate}{\relax}}{}{\item [{Date:}] \@memodate}` in the class. The problem I think is that `\today` is not expandable when `isodate` is loaded so the above test fails.